# SKShapeNode motionless when made the scene.frame a physicsBody

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, sprite-kit

It's my very first post in coding forum - it means i'm REEAAAAALLLY stuck (I've searched everywhere and tested many options).

Creating a simple bouncing ball on my ipad screen, coding the app using SpriteKit.

The below code prevent the ball to move at all BUT when i remove the SKPhysicsBody created out the frame.edge : the ball falls. 
I've got the feeling that the self.physicsBody is ultimately made as a volume despite I ask it to be made from an edge...

Can you please help ?

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0,dy: -6)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)  // ball's cage
    self.physicsBody?.friction = 0;

    let fbound = SKShapeNode(rect: self.frame)
    fbound.lineWidth = 1
    fbound.strokeColor = .red
    addChild(fbound)

    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: view.bounds.height / 2),
                radius: 15,
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: CGFloat.pi * 2,
                clockwise: true)

    let ball = SKShapeNode(path: path)
    ball.lineWidth = 1
    ball.fillColor = .red
    ball.strokeColor = .black
    ball.glowWidth = 0.5

    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.size.width/2)
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.mass = 0.6
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

    addChild(ball)
}
```

Please let me know if you need more details

Thanks a mil in advance

Rgds

Comment: When I run this in a blank SpriteKit project, the ball falls from the upper right-hand corner of the screen to the middle right-hand side of the screen, and bounces continuously. It works as a Mac app on my laptop, and as an iOS app on the "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)" simulator in Xcode. Try creating a new project and pasting this code in. Maybe you've done something elsewhere in your project that is causing this behavior, maybe in the storyboard?

Comment: use `view.showPhysics = true` to see if your bodies are in the correct places

Comment: Thanks to you both, Knight0fDragon your comment helped me to figure out that for some reasons my PhysicsBody on the ball was mis-centerd so i've edited as follow:
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.frame.size.width/2, center: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: view.bounds.height / 2))
Now it works!
Thanks all